# ConstraintViolationException when trying to persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I get the following error whenever I try to persist a child objects to a existing father object in JPA:

> Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [store.entidades.Sucursal] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
>   List of constraint violations:[
>       ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Por favor ingrese un valor en direccion', propertyPath=direccion, rootBeanClass=class store.entidades.Sucursal, messageTemplate='Por favor ingrese un valor en direccion'}
>       ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Por favor ingrese un valor en telefono', propertyPath=telefono, rootBeanClass=class store.entidades.Sucursal, messageTemplate='Por favor ingrese un valor en telefono'}
>   ]

This is the parent entity class that Im using:

```
    @Entity
    public class Sucursal {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;

        // nombre del encargado de esa sucursal
        private String subgerente;

        @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor en direccion")
        @Column(length = 120)
        private String direccion;

        @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor en telefono")
        @Column(length = 36, unique = true)
        private String telefono;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "producto_sucursal", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private List<Producto> producto = new ArrayList<Producto>();

        //getters and setters
```

This is the child entity class that Im using:

```
 @Entity
    public class Producto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String nombre;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    @Column(length = 140)
    private String descripcion;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private double precio;

    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String imagen1;
    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String imagen2;
    @NotNull(message = "Por favor ingrese un valor")
    private String imagen3;

    private int megusta;
    private int nomegusta;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "comentario_producto", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Comentario> comentario = new ArrayList<Comentario>();//

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "producto_subcategoria")
    private Subcategoria subcategoria = new Subcategoria();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "producto_categoria")
    private Categoria categoria = new Categoria();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "producto_sucursal")
    private Sucursal sucursal = new Sucursal();

    //getters and setters
```

My DAO class for Sucursal looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class SucursalDAO implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(Sucursal sucursal) {
        if (entityManager.find(Sucursal.class, sucursal.getId()) == null) {
            insertar(sucursal);

        } else {
            update(sucursal);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Whenever I click on a save button in front end it calls this method:

```
public void guardar() {

    System.out.println(newSucursal.getDireccion());
    System.out.println(newSucursal.getTelefono());

    for (int i = 0; i < listproductos.size(); i++) {

        // listproductos.get(i).setSucursal(newSucursal);
        System.out.println(listproductos.get(i).toString());

        newSucursal.getProductos().add(listproductos.get(i));
    }

    sucursalDAO.save(newSucursal);
}
```

When I call this save method I add the new child **Productos** to my **Sucursales** but when I try to persist the Parent it give me the error I posted above. 
I have tried many things but cant seem to figure out what the problem is?
Is there another way of saving child entities to existing parent entities?

**EDIT**

This is the code that fixed my problem for my save method:

```
public void guardar() {

        System.out.println(newSucursal.getDireccion());
        System.out.println(newSucursal.getTelefono());

        for (int i = 0; i < listproductos.size(); i++) {

            listproductos.get(i).setSucursal(newSucursal);

            Categoria cat = new Categoria();
            cat = categoriaDAO.read(listproductos.get(i).getCategoria().getId());
            listproductos.get(i).setCategoria(cat);

            Subcategoria subcat = new Subcategoria();
            subcat = subcategoriaDAO.read(listproductos.get(i).getSubcategoria().getId());
            listproductos.get(i).setSubcategoria(subcat);

            System.out.println(listproductos.get(i).toString());

            newSucursal.getProductos().add(listproductos.get(i));
        }

        // newSucursal.setProductos(listproductos);

        sucursalDAO.save(newSucursal);
    }
```

Comment: How could the values be getting emptied if I use my postconstruct to fetch them from the database ? I even printed them out on screen right before I call my save method and they are not null

Comment: Your `@ViewScoped` class and `@Entity` classes do not implement `Serializable`.

Comment: I added the `implements Serializable`, still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of your problem is that you need to assign both sides of your relationships:

```
public void guardar() {

    System.out.println(newSucursal.getDireccion());
    System.out.println(newSucursal.getTelefono());

    for (int i = 0; i < listproductos.size(); i++) {

        listproductos.get(i).setSucursal(newSucursal);
        System.out.println(listproductos.get(i).toString());

        newSucursal.getProductos().add(listproductos.get(i));
    }

    sucursalDAO.save(newSucursal);
}
```

which you have commented out for some reason.

Also, all of your `@ManyToOne` relationships are initialised with new objects like:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "producto_subcategoria")
private Subcategoria subcategoria = new Subcategoria();
```

which is asking for trouble because (again) the opposite sides of these relationships are never set.

Comment: Ahhh yes it flew past my head, when Im using bidirectional I have to assign from both sides, many thanks!!!! this fixed my problem. I will edit my question with the code that did the trick in case somebody else needs it.